# Which of these is the correct usage of the words "listen", "hear"?

Tags: verbs, sense-verbs

Which of these sentences is correct? Why?

> You must hear to this song.
>   You must listen to this song.
>   Have you heard to this song?
>   Have you listened to this song?

Comment: "Hear" should not be followed by "to".  The correct versions would be "You must hear this song" and "Have you heard this song?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is correct, but they have a slightly different emphasis in their meaning. *Hear* is generally regarded as a passive activity, something that happens whether one wants it to or not. *Listen*, on the other hand, is regarded as an active activity requiring the participation of the user.

I might say the following:

> You have got to hear this song.

If the person heard the song, and was unimpressed, I might then reply:

> Well, you must not have listened very
>   closely.

Answer (score 3):

As reported in another recent question, *listen* is an intransitive verb and does not take a direct object; you must use a prepositional phrase to specify the thing being perceived.  *Hear*, on the other hand, is transitive and can take an object, so you can say:

> You must **hear** this song.
>   Have you **heard** this song?
>   You must **listen to** this song.
>   Have you **listened to** this song?

Answer (score 1):

In the sentences you reported, you can use either *hear* or *listen*.

Generally speaking, *listen* and *hear* have similar meaning; two of the meanings of *hear* are *listen*, *pay attention*.

> She just doesn't hear what I'm telling her.

In specific contexts, *listen* is used instead of *hear*; for example, when a sentence uses the imperative mood, *listen* is used.

> Sit and listen to the radio.
>   Listen me when I am talking to you!

Comment: No, 50% of them are incorrect. Any native English speaker would pick up on this.

Comment: I will rephrase the answer to report what I exactly mean.