# Do I say "Hear the voice of reason" or "Listen to the voice of reason" or either?

Tags: meaning, verbs, idioms

Although I say "Listen to reason," if I insert "voice of," do I use "Listen to the voice of reason" or "Hear the voice of reason," or can I use either? The topic came up in a class I was giving distinguishing between TO HEAR as a sense verb (not deliberate, involuntary) and TO LISTEN as a deliberate, voluntary verb.

Comment: You can use either one.  The choice depends largely on the "tone" of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The word "hear" actually has both meanings. [As Cambridge notes,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hear) the word "hear" can mean "to listen to someone or something with great attention."